# Finding the busiest time-frame in a parking lot

Tags: c#, performance, linq, interval

The text file containing cars' arrival and departure time will upload stuff from the parking lot.

Text will be like this:

```
10:10, 11:10
10:30, 12:40 
10:25, 11:10
11:10, 12:20
```

I created a `ParkedCar` class:

```
public class ParkerCar
{
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
}
```

The method that parses the text file, fills into `List<ParkedCar>`, and sorts them by the cars' arrival time:

```
public class ParkingLotRepository
{
    public List<ParkedCar> getParkedCars()
    {
        List<ParkedCar> parkedCars = new List<ParkedCar>();
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path))
        {
            string[] times = line.Split(',');
            bool isValid = true;
            DateTime dtStart;
            if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(times[0].Trim(), "HH:mm",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out dtStart))
                isValid = false;

            DateTime dtEnd;
            if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(times[1].Trim(), "HH:mm",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out dtEnd))
                isValid = false;

            if (isValid)
            {
                parkedCars.Add(new ParkedCar
                {
                    ArrivalTime = dtStart,
                    DepartureTime = dtEnd
                });
            }
        }
        parkedCars = parkedCars
            .OrderBy(c => c.ArrivalTime)
            .ThenBy(c => c.DepartureTime)
            .ToList();

        return parkedCars;
    }
}
```

I wrote the method shown below to find the busiest time-frame and how many cars were in the parking lot. I'm not sure if this is an effective way to do that:

```
public static ParkTimeframe getPickTimeframe(List<ParkedCar> cars)
{
    List<ParkTimeframe> timeFrames = new List<ParkTimeframe>();
    DateTime dtStart = cars.First().arrivalTime;
    DateTime dtEnd = cars.First().leavingTime;
    int count = 0;

    foreach (ParkedCar car in cars)
    {
        if (car.arrivalTime <= dtEnd && car.arrivalTime >= dtStart)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            timeFrames.Add(new ParkTimeframe
            {
                startTime = dtStart,
                endTime = dtEnd,
                countCars = count
            });
            dtStart = car.arrivalTime;
            dtEnd = car.leavingTime;
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    int maxCountCar = timeFrames.Max(x => x.countCars);
    return timeFrames.First(x => x.countCars == maxCountCar);
}

public class ParkedCar
{
    public DateTime arrivalTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime leavingTime { get; set; }
}
```

Also, is there a better way to do that using LINQ?

Comment: I noticed you create a timeframe based on each car. Wouldn't that skew the results towards the car that stays the longest? For example, if the lot is open from 8 AM - 11 PM, and a car parks at 8:01 AM and leaves at 10:59 PM, won't your method return a timeframe that is 14:58? That may reduce the effectiveness of your method.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand

Comment: Your method will return the largest timeframe that a car spent in your parking lot. If your lot is open between 0800h and 2300h, and a car is parked there between 8:01 and 22:59, then your method output is basically going to tell you that your parking lot was busy during the time that it was open.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on exactly what you need? I'm guessing that you want the time that there were the maximum number of cars in the carpark?

Comment: yes @RobH to be more specific, I want the time-frame when in the parking lot were the maximum number of cars

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 7):

**Naming Conventions**

[MSDN, General Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)

- DO NOT use Hungarian notation:

  - [dt]Start in `getPickTimeframe()` --> `DateTime currentFrameStartDate`
  - [dt]End in `getPickTimeframe()` --> `DateTime currentFrameEndDate`
- DO favor readability over brevity:

  - `ParkedCar` --> `ParkingLog`
  - `getPickTimeframe(List<ParkedCar> [cars])` --> `GetPeakTimeFrame(List<ParkingLog> parkingLogs)`
  - `public int [countCars];` --> `public int TotalNumberOfParkedCars;`
  - `int [count] = 0;` --> `int currentFrameNumberOfParkedCars;`

  [MSDN, Naming Guidelines / Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx)
- DO use PascalCasing for all public member, type, and namespace names consisting of multiple words:

  - [G]et[Pick]Time[F]rame() --> `GetPeakTimeFrame()`
  - class ParkTime[F]rame
  - ParkTime[F]rame.[S]tartTime
  - ParkTime[F]rame.[E]ndTime
  - ParkTime[F]rame.[C]ountCars --> Also see above for alternative name
  - ParkedCar.[A]rrivalTime
  - ParkedCar.[L]eavingTime

**Implementation**

Your current implementation, besides efficiency, is not working correctly.

For parkings as the following:

```
// Parking opens at 07:00
DateTime parkingOpenDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(7);

// t --xxxxxxxx--------------------------------07:02 - 07:10
// t ---xxxxxxxx-------------------------------07:03 - 07:11
// t --------------xxxxxxxx--------------------07:14 - 07:22
// t --------xxxxxxxxx-------------------------07:08 - 07:17
// t 001222223321112221111100000000000000000000

new ParkingLog[]
{
    new ParkingLog() { ArrivalTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(2), LeavingTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(10) },
    new ParkingLog() { ArrivalTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(3), LeavingTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(11) },
    new ParkingLog() { ArrivalTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(14), LeavingTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(22) },
    new ParkingLog() { ArrivalTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(8), LeavingTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(17) }
}
```

It should output

```
07:08.00 - 07:10:00 with 3 cars
```

However, it outputs:

```
07:02.00 - 07:10:00 with 2 cars
```

Here are my changes to the code, calculating the correct peak time frame, only assuming the `LeavingDate` of each `ParkingLog` (`ParkedCar` in your source) is greater than the `ArrivalDate`:

```
public class _113182
{
    private SortedList<DateTime, int> carParkCapacityTracker = new SortedList<DateTime, int>();

    public class ParkingTimeFrame
    {
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public int TotalNumberOfParkedCars { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0:HH:mm.ss} - {1:HH:mm:ss} | #Cars: {2}", StartTime, EndTime, TotalNumberOfParkedCars);
        }
    }

    public class ParkingLog
    {
        public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime LeavingTime { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss} - {1:HH:mm:ss}", ArrivalTime, LeavingTime);
        }
    }

    private void TrackCarParkingAction(DateTime actionDate, int actionEffect)
    {
        if (!carParkCapacityTracker.ContainsKey(actionDate))
        {
            carParkCapacityTracker.Add(actionDate, actionEffect);
        }
        else
        {
            carParkCapacityTracker[actionDate] += actionEffect;
        }
    }

    private void TrackCarParkingAction(ParkingLog parkingLog)
    {
        TrackCarParkingAction(parkingLog.ArrivalTime, +1);
        TrackCarParkingAction(parkingLog.LeavingTime, -1);
    }

    public ParkingTimeFrame GetPeakTimeFrame(List<ParkingLog> parkingLogs)
    {
        carParkCapacityTracker.Clear();

        parkingLogs.ForEach(TrackCarParkingAction);

        int currentNumberOfParkedCars = 0;
        int maximumNumberOfParkedCars = 0;
        int maximumCapacityFrameOffset = 0;

        for (int currentFrameOffset =  0; currentFrameOffset < carParkCapacityTracker.Count; currentFrameOffset++)
        {
            currentNumberOfParkedCars += carParkCapacityTracker.Values[currentFrameOffset];
            if (maximumNumberOfParkedCars <= currentNumberOfParkedCars)
            {
                maximumNumberOfParkedCars = currentNumberOfParkedCars;
                maximumCapacityFrameOffset = currentFrameOffset;
            }
        }

        return new ParkingTimeFrame()
        {
            StartTime = carParkCapacityTracker.Keys[maximumCapacityFrameOffset],
            EndTime = carParkCapacityTracker.Keys[maximumCapacityFrameOffset + 1],
            TotalNumberOfParkedCars = maximumNumberOfParkedCars
        };
    }
}
```

And here is the code to test it:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter to start..");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // Parking opens at 07:00
    DateTime parkingOpenDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(7);

    List<ParkingLog> parkingLogs = new List<ParkingLog>
    (
        // t --xxxxxxxx--------------------------------07:02 - 07:10
        // t ---xxxxxxxx-------------------------------07:03 - 07:11
        // t --------------xxxxxxxx--------------------07:14 - 07:22
        // t --------xxxxxxxxx-------------------------07:08 - 07:17
        // t 001222223321112221111100000000000000000000

        new ParkingLog[]
        {
            new ParkingLog() { ArrivalTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(2), LeavingTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(10) },
            new ParkingLog() { ArrivalTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(3), LeavingTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(11) },
            new ParkingLog() { ArrivalTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(14), LeavingTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(22) },
            new ParkingLog() { ArrivalTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(8), LeavingTime = parkingOpenDate.AddMinutes(17) }
        }
    );

    // Should output 07:08 - 07:10 with 3 cars
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", new _113182().GetPeakTimeFrame(parkingLogs));
}
```

**Edit:**

The OP told me that he tested the code and the code failed.

I tested it with the same input (as documented in the question by the OP) and it produced the correct result:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // According to the data provided by the OP
    // 10:10, 11:10
    // 10:30, 12:40 
    // 10:25, 11:10
    // 11:10, 12:20

    //       10:00    10:10    10:25    10:30    11:10    12:20    12:40    
    // CAR 1            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    // CAR 2                              xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    // CAR 3                     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    // CAR 4                                       xxxxxxxxxx

    // The peak time frame should be: 10:30 - 11:10 with 3 cars:

    List<ParkingLog> parkingLogs = getParkedCars();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", new _113182().GetPeakTimeFrame(parkingLogs));
}
```

**Output:**

```
10:30.00 - 11:10:00 | #Cars: 3
```

**Edit 2:**

The OP provided new test data and asserted that the code fails with this data.

Here is my test, and it works as expected, or there is something wrong and we are not on the same page:

```
// According to the new data provided by the OP
//09:00, 15:00
//10:10, 11:10
//10:30, 12:40
//10:35, 11:20
//10:25, 11:10
//11:10, 12:20

//       09:00    10:10    10:25    10:30    10:35    11:10    11:20    12:20    12:40    15:00
// CAR 1   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
// CAR 2            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
// CAR 3                              xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
// CAR 4                                       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
// CAR 5                     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
// CAR 6                                                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

// The peak time frame should be: 10:35 - 11:10 with 5 cars:

List<ParkingLog> parkingLogs = getParkedCars();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", new _113182().GetPeakTimeFrame(parkingLogs));
```

And the output is:

```
10:35.00 - 11:10:00 | #Cars: 5
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32798/discussion-on-answer-by-oguz-ozgul-finding-the-busiest-time-frame-in-a-parking-l).

Answer (score 4):

You have an issue where if a car parks for a really long time, your method will probably return that timespan, which might not be very useful if it is pretty much the entire time your lot is open.

I would recommend specifying an interval of time beforehand that you want to check, and calculate the number of cars in each increment of that interval until closing time.

```
void Main()
{
    var calculator = new ParkingLotCalculator(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0), new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0), 30);
    var cars = new[]
    {
        new ParkedCar(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0)),
        new ParkedCar(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 10, 59, 0), new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0)),
    };

    var result = calculator.CalculateBusiestTime(cars);
}

public class ParkingLotCalculator
{
    private readonly DateTime _openTime;
    private readonly DateTime _closeTime;
    private readonly int _timeFrameDuration;

    public ParkingLotCalculator(DateTime openTime, DateTime closeTime, int timeFrameDuration)
    {
        _openTime = openTime;
        _closeTime = closeTime;
        _timeFrameDuration = timeFrameDuration;
    }

    public ParkingLotTimeFrame CalculateBusiestTime(IEnumerable<ParkedCar> cars)
    {
        return CreateTimeFrames(cars).OrderByDescending(timeFrame => timeFrame.NumberOfCars).First();
    }

    private IEnumerable<ParkingLotTimeFrame> CreateTimeFrames(IEnumerable<ParkedCar> cars)
    {
        var startTime = _openTime;
        DateTime endTime;
        while((endTime = startTime.AddMinutes(_timeFrameDuration)) <= _closeTime)
        {
            yield return new ParkingLotTimeFrame(startTime, endTime, cars);
            startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(_timeFrameDuration);
        } 
        yield break;
    }
}

public struct ParkingLotTimeFrame
{
    public readonly DateTime Start;
    public readonly DateTime End;
    public readonly int NumberOfCars;

    public ParkingLotTimeFrame(DateTime start, DateTime end, IEnumerable<ParkedCar> cars) : this()
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
        NumberOfCars = cars.Count(WasCarParked);
    }

    private bool WasCarParked(ParkedCar car)
    {
        if(car.ArrivalTime < Start)
            return car.DepartureTime > Start;
        return car.ArrivalTime < End;
    }
}

public struct ParkedCar
{
    public readonly DateTime ArrivalTime;
    public readonly DateTime DepartureTime;

    public ParkedCar(DateTime arrivalTime, DateTime departureTime)
    {
        ArrivalTime = arrivalTime;
        DepartureTime = departureTime;
    }
}
```

It's unclear what should be done when there are two equally-busy intervals. Currently your code just takes the first one it finds which is essentially what I've continued to do.

If it seems weird to pass cars to a timespan that they might not have even been parked for, then you can move the calculation logic into the calculator:

```
private IEnumerable<ParkingLotTimeFrame> CreateTimeFrames(IEnumerable<ParkedCar> cars)
{
    var startTime = _openTime;
    DateTime endTime;
    while((endTime = startTime.AddMinutes(_timeFrameDuration)) <= _closeTime)
    {
        var numberOfCarsParked = cars.Count(car => WasCarParked(startTime, endTime, car));
        yield return new ParkingLotTimeFrame(startTime, endTime, numberOfCarsParked);
        startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(_timeFrameDuration);
    } 
    yield break;
}

private bool WasCarParked(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, ParkedCar car)
{
    if(car.ArrivalTime < startTime)
        return car.DepartureTime > startTime;
    return car.ArrivalTime < endTime;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! 
Stuff from the parking lot will upload text file with cars' arrival and departure times. That's why I think there is no need to care at what time  the parking lot was open and closed.

Comment: By the way I didn't understand why we should pass timeFrameDuration variable.

Comment: @Nurlan If your duration is not a constant number, then you will have inconsistent results. How do you know that a 10-hour interval for which 1000 cars were parked is busier than a 1-hour interval during which 200 cars were parked? You can't simply compare numbers if you don't make the time frame constant.

Comment: We have arrival and departure times sorted by ArrivalTime property, I'm initializing dtStart and  dtEnd respectively with first element's ArrivalTiem and DepartureTime of the list, iterating the list comparing car's arrival time with dtStart, and if currently compared car's arrival time lower or equal than dtStart and departure time higher than dtEnd, setting dtEnd to that value. So what's the need to use time frame duration, I can't understand, also as I noted above, I don't need to set open and close times for parking lot, I parse text file, processing the data from text.

Comment: @Nurlan Your time frame is variable, meaning it is tied to the duration that a car stays in the lot. Let's take an extreme example and say that a car stays in the lot for a year. Your resulting timeframe is going to be a year long. Now, it's not really helpful to get a result that says "2015 was a busy year," now is it?

Comment: as I noted above stuff from parking lot will upload a text file, that contains arrival and departure time, my task is not to handle extreme cases, here my task is to parse a text file, sort them, and find the busiest time-frame. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Nurlan Nobody's wrong here, I'm just pointing out that even in cases that are not extreme, the resulting timeframe's duration is completely variable. With one set of data you could end up with a timeframe of ten minutes and with another set of data you could end up with a timeframe of ten days. That may make your program not very effective as large timeframes may not be helpful. I was suggesting making the timeframe interval fixed so that you can guarantee that the result is within a helpful range of time. Then if the results aren't what you want, you can rerun with a different interval.

Comment: I like the way you analyze some cases, but I think you're confused of usage of DateTime types for arrival and departure times, in text file they will only be in HH:mm, so facing with the case you noted above should be impossible.

Comment: @Nurlan Okay, but the problem remains; see previous comment. If you're only running this within 1 day, and someone stays all day, then your timeframe will be the whole day, which may not be a helpful result.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I got the idea. But I think time frame duration should be a minute, say some group of cars (in this case they have the same arrival and departure time) have stayed for 23 minutes. Won't we miss this cars?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32750/discussion-between-nurlan-and-moarboilerplate).

Comment: @Nurlan can't do chat, but the code I wrote takes that into account. It creates a contiguous range of timeframes between a start and end, and then for every timeframe, calculates whether a car was parked during that time or not. Also you may want to consider using TimeSpan instead of DateTime since the dates don't matter.